# Write column in file

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to write rows from SQL into text file.

My codes:

```
result = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SWN_all_result.txt'
result_file = open(result, 'w')
sql_select2 = "select * from test01"
c.execute(sql_select2)
rows2 = c.fetchall()
for detail2 in rows2:
    Sentence = detail2[1]
    SWN_Note = detail2[4]
    print Sentence, '\t', SWN_Note, '\n'
    result_file.write(Sentence + '\t' + SWN_Note + '\n')
result_file.close()
db.close()
```

The results showed:

```
abc
    neutral 

cdf
    positive
```

How I can make them in the same line as I mentioned in the codes?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have to have newlines in your data. Strip those before printing and writing to the file:

```
Sentence = detail2[1].rstrip('\n')
```